# How to configure an Android project flavor in multiple (library) modules in Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following module structure:

```
:app (Android)
:data (Android)
...
```

With `:app` being dependent on `:data`

I also have the following endpoint flavors:

```
dev
acc
prod
```

I'm looking for a way to define an *endpoint string* in the `:data` module and set the *applicationIdSuffix* in the `:app` module, based on the same flavor.

I have an EndPointFlavor enum class in the buildSrc module:

```
enum class EndpointFlavor(
   val key: String,
   val applicationIdSuffix: String,
   val endpointUrl: String,
) { Dev(...), Acc(...), Prod(...) }
```

My current approach:

**app/build.gradle.kts**

```
android {
    flavorDimensions.add(EndpointFlavor.dimension)
    productFlavors {
        EndpointFlavor.values().forEach { flavor ->
            create(flavor.key) {
                dimension = EndpointFlavor.dimension
                applicationIdSuffix = flavor.applicationIdSuffix
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**data/build.gradle.kts**

```
android {
    flavorDimensions.add(EndpointFlavor.dimension)
    productFlavors {
        EndpointFlavor.values().forEach { flavor ->
            create(flavor.key) {
                dimension = EndpointFlavor.dimension
                buildConfigField("String", "endpointUrl", flavor.endpointUrl)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This syncs, but I get the following error when building:

> Unresolved dependencies
>
> The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably
> optimized for Android, as well as attribute
> 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug',
> attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value
> '7.3.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value
> 'androidJvm'. However we cannot choose between the following variants
> of project :data
>
> - accDebugApiElements
> - devDebugApiElements
> - prodDebugApiElements
> - Variant 'accDebugApiElements' capability Project.data:unspecified declares an API of a component,
>   preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute
>   'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.0',
>   attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value
>   'debug', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value
>   'androidJvm':
>
>   - Unmatched attributes:
>
>     - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:endPoint' with value
>       'acc' but the consumer didn't ask for it
>     - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value
>       'accDebug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
>     - Provides attribute 'endPoint' with value 'acc' but the consumer didn't ask for it
>     - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
>       ...

I tried to only configure the flavor in the `:data` module, but I do not have access to setting the *applicationIdSuffix* there.

What would be the right approach to configure a flavor in a single place and use that to configure the flavor in multiple modules?